# How to get List of Only Purchased Product Ids fron inApp in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am having an app in which I have 5 Non Consumable In App Purchases.

On every Single In App Purchase I Update my DB with the images.

There are 5 Packages for 5 Non Consumable In App Purchases.

Now there is a Restore Purchase Functionality as it is a Non Consumable In App Purchase.

There is a single Restore Button in my app. But How to identify that Which Product has already being purchased?

I use the following code for restoring in app purchase. But it doesn't update my DB because it doesn't know which products are previously purchased.

```
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Pack1"])
    {
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"])
        {
           // app already launched
           NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
       }
       else
       {
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"];
           NSLog(@"Launching first time");
           requestText= @"Animal";
           [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
           [self getdata];
       }
}


else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Pack2"])
{

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"])
    {
        // app already launched
        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"];
        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
        requestText= @"Celebrity";
        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
        [self getdata];
    }

}

else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Pack3"])
{

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"])
    {
        // app already launched
        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"];
        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
        requestText= @"Nature";
        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
        [self getdata];
    }
}
```

How to get list of only purchased Product Ids?

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restore the purchases by using :

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

then **SKPaymentTransactionObserver** will call its

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

with the **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased** transaction state. You can see that it returns an **Array** for the transactions. 
You can get a single transaction using,

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    NSLog(@"Purchased indentifier : %@", transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
}
```

This will print out the identifiers that the user have purchased. You can set your **NSUserDefaults** regarding to these values

Comment: :Thanks for you reply. I will try this.

Answer (score 4):

For getting list of purchased products, you can call below function :

```
[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

This will return the list of previously purchased items.

You can find more details [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1) is the apple's documentation.